# write a function to convert different date formats in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, pycharm

I am learning `Python` using `Pycharm`. I am trying to write a function to convert different date formats into 1 date format. In particular, I want to let the function know what format it is and what format I want, and can use this function for any future datasets. I am dealing with quite large datasets ( 20gb for now but will need to work on a 200gb dataset later).

so far I have tried this:

```
import csv
df = csv.DictReader(open('dataset.csv'))

def format_date(df, dateformat):
    """this will format the column containing dates'"""
    for row in df:
        row['Date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%Y%m%d')
        csv.DictWriter(str(df)+'_converted.csv', data)
        return
```

so far I know that this function,

```
(row['Date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%Y%m%d'))
```

works as I tried to print it out. however, how do I write all of these rows with the updated `"Date"` column into a new csv file? and is there a way for, say in the future, I can just put it the format of the unwanted date (i.e. `format_date(df,yyyy/mm/yy)` and `Python` will spit out a new csv file containing the new date formats

Comment: you make your format string a variable ... and then you should use strftime to output time in a given format ... also `python-dateutil` can parse just about any date format ... it just figures it out (by going through a list of common formats)

Comment: what is `data` you are referring to in `csv.DictWriter` line of code

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of possible date formats. Iterate over it and try to convert the date.

Something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

ALLOWED_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d', '%d.%m.%Y']

def convert_date(string):

    for format in ALLOWED_FORMATS:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(string, format)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

This is the way how Django's DatetimeField does it, if you have already Django in your project you could just pass your string to a DatetimeField instance.

The order of formats in the list might matter to avoid incorrect parsings. However, if the date formats are to diverse, their could be actual ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for how to write new updated csv to file.

To write a row using `csv.DictWriter` for writing a row to CSV file

```
output_file = open('output.csv','w')
df2 = csv.DictWriter(output_file, row.keys()) #row.keys() is to write headers to output CSV file which are `keys` of row
df2.writeheader()
df2.writerow(row)
```